# Want to store detected cropped images in a file

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I have successfully detected human faces using haarcascade in opencv. I have run a loop in which it will crop only the detected portion of the image and store into the system. But it crops only one detected face and rest of the faces doesn't get cropped and save into the system. I am attaching my code. please help to to solve my issue. Eg. if image contains 4 people then haarcascade detect 4 faces but the loop only crops one detected image and rest 3 images does not get cropped..!

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

public class FaceDetection
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);


    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier();

 faceDetector.load("G:\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
    //System.out.println ( "Working" );
    // Input image
    Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("G:\\sample.jpg");

    // Detecting faces
    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);
    System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", 
            faceDetections.toArray().length));
    // Creating a rectangular box showing faces detected
    Rect rectCrop=null;
    for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray())
    {
        Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
         new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                                       new Scalar(0, 255, 0),2);
        rectCrop = new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);

    }

    Rect[] count = faceDetections.toArray();
    System.out.println(""+count.length);

    // Saving the output image
    String filename = "Ouput.jpg";
    Imgcodecs.imwrite("G:\\"+filename, image);

    Mat markedImage = new Mat(image,rectCrop);

    Imgcodecs.imwrite("G:\\crop1.jpg",markedImage );

}
}
```

Comment: did the code work? @omkarlanghe

Comment: Code executed successfully..Thank you..! @TheOneWhoMade

Comment: If the answer helps, then accept the answer using the checkmark below the voting system. @omkarlanghe

Comment: It can be useful: https://github.com/ahmetozlu/face_recognition_crop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is looping over all of them and choosing the last face and then saving that face. You need it to either a) crop them separately and add meta that tags them together, or b)crop them all together.

For option a, inside your loop, you need to save each file separately. Simply move you saving file code into your loop and adjust it so that it works.

For option b, you might need some additional software to crop all of the faces together. This could be done a number of ways. You could concatenate all of the a)pixle arrays, or b)individual bytes. Then when you need to find connections between people you simply have to run the face recognition software on the files again.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to do that?? @TheOneWhoMade

Comment: Both one..!! It will help me to understand better..! @TheOneWhoMade

Comment: Inside your loop, you need to save each file seperatly. Simply move you saving file code into your loop and adjust it so that it works. @omkarlanghe

Comment: Ok please..! suggest me where to make changes in code!! @TheOneWhoMade

Comment: Ok Thank you i will get back to you in sometime..!@TheOneWhoMade

Comment: For option b, you might need some additional software to crop all of the faces together. This could be done a number of ways. You could concatenate all of the a)pixle arrays, or b)individual bytes. Then when you need to find connections between people you simply have to run the face recognition software on the files again. @omkarlanghe

Comment: I think I have a working example for option A. please see: http://jsfiddle.net/qxk23u1a/ (the java is in the js section) @omkarlanghe